# Unresolved resource dependencies [arn:aws:s3:::alberto313131/*] in the Resources block of the template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I am getting the error above when trying to create a AWS CloudFormation script through the console designer. I am certain that the bucket alberto313131 exists.

Here is the full error:

```
Template contains errors.: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [arn:aws:s3:::alberto313131/*] in the Resources block of the template
```

This is the full script, I am using:

```
Resources:
  S3BP1KK1X:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::BucketPolicy'
    Properties:
      Bucket: 
        Ref: "arn:aws:s3:::alberto313131/*"
      PolicyDocument: 
        Statement:
          - Sid: AddPerm
            Effect: Allow
            Principal: '*'
            Action:
              - "s3:GetObject"
            Resource:
              - "arn:aws:s3:::alberto313131/*"
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [CloudFormation S3 BucketPolicy doco](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-policy.html#w2ab1c21c10d210c17c11)

> Properties
>
> Bucket
>
> The name of the Amazon S3 bucket to which the policy applies.

So, you simply provide the bucket name, not the ARN.

Only for the `Resource` inside the `Statement` section of the `PolicyDocument` do you provide the ARN.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I am going to provide an alternative answer that also got my problem solved as well

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get past my issue using the logical id.

```
Resources:
  resbucket:
    Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket"
    Properties: 
      BucketName: "testathena44"
  resbucketpolicy:
    Type: "AWS::S3::BucketPolicy"
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref resbucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          -
            Sid: "ABC123"
            Action:
              - "s3:GetObject"
            Effect: Allow
            Resource: !Join ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::", !Ref resbucket, "/*"]]
            Principal:
              AWS:
                - "*"
```

Comment: That is of course the best way - but in your question you hadn't specified that you were also creating the bucket in your template. My presumption was that it already existed.